# Eclipse cleans target (with its WEB-INF/lib) folder before running app

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, maven-eclipse-plugin

It's not a question but I'm sure it can help someone else because it has happened to almost everyone in my company too.

The context:
I'm working with **Eclipse** on a **Java GWT Maven project** with the **Eclipse Google Plugin**.

Once, I updated my dependencies so I executed the command
`mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`
to update my Eclipse project.

But then everytime I wanted to run my app, Eclipse cleaned the **target** directory (included the **WEB-INF/lib** folder).

To solve it:

1. delete manually the **.settings** folder under your root project folder
2. re-execute `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`
3. (optional - depend of your env) re-set properly Google settings (WAR directory, Entry Point Modules...)

[image]

Comment: The Maven Eclipse Plugin has been lacking updates since January 2012 and IMHO people should definitely consider switching to m2e instead. You are riding a dead horse here.

Comment: @Freddy: consider answering your own question (rather than including the answer within the question), and then try to formulate the question as… a question ;-) (AFAICT, that's _also_ how StackOverflow is supposed to be used)